# Programa no lee el último método numérico

Tags: c++, método, dev-c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que utilice unos métodos numéricos pero al tratar de resolver el de 3/8 de *Simpson* el programa no lee lo que debería, donde podría estar el error.

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <iomanip>
       #include <cmath>
       #include <iostream>  
       using namespace std;
       void pedirDatos();
       int **puntero_matriz;
    main (){
    int fila=1;
    int fila2=1;
    int f,c,columnas,columnas2,n;
    int j,suma=0;
    float numero[100][100];
    float numero2[100][100];
  char i;
  float a,b,H,trapecio,simpson1,simpson2;
    char salida='k';
while ((salida=='k')||(salida=='K')){

cout<< "Metodos de Integracion Numerico\n";
cout<< "\n";
cout<< "A. Metodo de Trapecio\n";
cout<< "B. Metodo de 1/3 de Simpson\n";
cout<< "C. Metodo de 3/8 de Simpson\n";
cout<< "\n";
cout<< "Ingrese la letra del Metodo Seleccionado  :";cin>> i;
system ("cls");
       switch (i) { 
        case 'a' : case 'A' :
            cout << "Trapecio\n";
            cout<< "\n";
            cout<< "Introduzca su N =  ";cin>>n;
            cout<< "Punto A =  ";cin>>a;
            cout<< "Punto B =  ";cin>>b;
            cout<< "\n";
            if (a==-a)
            {
                H=(b+a)/n;
            }
            else
            {
                H=(b-a)/n;
            }
            {
            cout<< "El valor de su H es:"<<H;
            cout<<"\n";
            }
            for ( f=0;f<fila;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++)
                {
                    cout<<"Digite su X["<<f<<"]["<<c<<"]: ";
                    cin >>numero[f][c];
                }
            }
                for ( f=0;f<fila2;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++)
                {
                    cout<<"Digite un Y["<<f<<"]["<<c<<"]: ";
                    cin >>numero2[f][c];
                }
            }
            system("cls");

            cout << "\n\n Metodo de Trapecio\n";
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<setprecision(2)<<"Su H es: "<<H;
            cout<<"\n\n\n";
            {

            for( f=0;f<fila;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++ )
                {
                    cout<<"\t"<<numero[f][c];
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
                for( f=0;f<fila2;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++ )
                {
                    cout<<"\t"<<numero2[f][c];

                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }

            for(j=a;j<=n-1;j++){
                suma=suma+(2*numero2[0][j]);
            }
            cout<<suma;
            suma=suma+numero2[0][n]+numero[0][0];
            trapecio=(H/2)*suma;

         }
         cout<<setprecision(2)<< "\nEl Trapecio es: "<<trapecio;

             break;
        case 'b' :case 'B' :
            cout << "1/3 De Simpson\n";
            cout<< "\n";
            cout<< "Introduzca su N =  ";cin>>n;
            if(n%2!=0)
            break;
            cout<< "Punto A =  ";cin>>a;
            cout<< "Punto B =  ";cin>>b;
            cout<< "\n";

            if (a==-a)
            {
                H=(b+a)/n;
            }
            else
            {
                H=(b-a)/n;
            }
            cout<< "El valor de su H es:"<<H;
            cout<<"\n";

            for ( f=0;f<fila;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++)
                {
                    cout<<"Digite su X["<<f<<"]["<<c<<"]: ";
                    cin >>numero[f][c];
                }
            }
                for ( f=0;f<fila2;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++)
                {
                    cout<<"Digite un Y["<<f<<"]["<<c<<"]: ";
                    cin >>numero2[f][c];
                }
            }
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n\n1/3 De Simpson\n";
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"El valor de su H es: "<<H;
            cout<< "\nEl valor de trapecio es: "<<simpson1;
            cout<<"\n\n\n";

            for( f=0;f<fila;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++ )
                {
                    cout<<"\t"<<numero[f][c];
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
                for( f=0;f<fila2;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++ )
                {
                    cout<<"\t"<<numero2[f][c];
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
            for(j=a;j<=n-1;j++){
                suma=suma+(2*numero2[0][j]);
            }
            cout<<suma;
            suma=suma+numero2[0][n]+numero[0][0];
            simpson1=(H/2)*suma;

         }

        break;
            switch (i) { //abre switch
            case 'c' :case 'C' :
            cout << "-----------------3/8 DE Smpson-----------------\n";
            cout<< "\n";
            cout<< "Introduzca su N =  ";cin>>n;
            cout<< "Intoduzca su punto A =  ";cin>>a;
            cout<< "Intoduzca su punto B =  ";cin>>b;
            cout<< "\n";
            if (a==-a)
            {
                H=(b+a)/n;
            }
            else
            {
                H=(b-a)/n;
            }
            cout<< "El valor de su H es: "<<H;
            cout<<"\n";

            for ( f=0;f<fila;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++)
                {
                    cout<<"Diguite su X["<<f<<"]["<<c<<"]: ";
                    cin >>numero[f][c];
                }
            }
                for ( f=0;f<fila2;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++)
                {
                    cout<<"Diguite un Y["<<f<<"]["<<c<<"]: ";
                    cin >>numero2[f][c];
                }
            }
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n\n             3/8 DE Smpson      \n";
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"El valor de su H es: "<<H;
            cout<< "\nEl valor de trapecio es: "<<simpson2;
            cout<<"\n\n\n";

            for( f=0;f<fila;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++ )
                {
                    cout<<"\t"<<numero[f][c];
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
                for( f=0;f<fila2;f++)
            {
                for( c=0;c<n+1;c++ )
                {
                    cout<<"\t"<<numero2[f][c];
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }   
            if(n==3)
            {
                simpson2=(3/8)*(H)*(numero2[f][c]+(3*numero2[f][c])+
          (3*numero2[f][c])+numero2[f][c]);
            }
        default :
            cout << "\aLa opcion no es VALIDA \n ";
            break;
    }
    cout<< "\n";
    cout << "Si desea continuar oprima 'K' -->";cin>>salida;
    system("cls");
}
    cout<< "\n";
    cout << "FIN";
    cout<< "\n";
 }
```

Comment: Hola Humberto, bienvenido a SOes. Esta es la versión de habla hispana de SO, lo que quiere decir que el único idioma permitido es el español. Te sugiero seguir el [tour] y leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas.

Answer (score 3):

Tu programa tiene algunas características que lo hacen poco legible y propenso a errores:

- No está correctamente tabulado. Es imposible revisar un código que no está tabulado correctamente si no es con la ayuda de un IDE.
- Todo el código se encuentra en la misma función. Tu código daría para tener fácilmente 4 o 5 funciones. Tener porciones de código más pequeñas y manejables ayuda a detectar y prevenir errores.
- Usas variables globales ¿Por qué? En programas tan simples no tiene ningún sentido.

Y luego están cosas como estas:

```
switch (i) { 
    case 'a' : case 'A' :
    // ...
        break;
    case 'b' :case 'B' :
    // ...
    break;

    switch (i) { // <<----
        case 'c' :case 'C' :
```

¿Adivinas cuándo se va a ejecutar la opción de 3/8? Exacto, **nunca**. Tienes el primer switch con dos opciones, `A` y `B` y dentro de la `B` tienes un nuevo `switch` para la opción `C`... Además, al encontrarse este nuevo `switch` pasado el `break` ten por seguro que la ejecución no va a pasar nunca por este segundo `switch`. En este cso la solución es tan sencilla como eliminar el segundo `switch` y la correspondiente llave de cierre (y aquí es cuando cobra especial importancia tener el código tabulado).

Otras características raras de tu código (sin efectos por ahora en el resultado):

- Creas ámbitos sin sentido:

  ```
  case 'a' : case 'A' :
      cout << "Trapecio\n";
      cout<< "\n";
      cout<< "Introduzca su N =  ";cin>>n;
      cout<< "Punto A =  ";cin>>a;
      cout<< "Punto B =  ";cin>>b;
      cout<< "\n";
      if (a==-a)
      {
          H=(b+a)/n;
      }
      else
      {
          H=(b-a)/n;
      }
      { // <<---
          cout<< "El valor de su H es:"<<H;
          cout<<"\n";
      } // <<---
  ```

  Si no hay una razón para crear ámbitos no los definas porque luego te pueden asaltar dudas ¿Esto no debería ir dentro de un `if` o un `else`? ¿Habré borrado algo por error? Además de que en otras circunstancias pueden provocar errores difíciles de detectar.
- No es necesario declarar todas las variables al principio:

  ```
  main (){
      int fila=1;
      int fila2=1;
      int f,c,columnas,columnas2,n;
      int j,suma=0;
      float numero[100][100];
      float numero2[100][100];
      char i;
      float a,b,H,trapecio,simpson1,simpson2;
      char salida='k';
  ```

  Y no solo no es necesario sino que es contrarpoducente. Las variables tienen que tener una vida lo más pequeña posible y ya verás como con el tiempo me acabarás dando la razón.

  Es preferible, por ejemplo, declarar los bucles así:

  ```
  for( int f=0; f<fila; f++ )
  ```
- En C++ `main` **SIEMPRE** debe devolver `int`:

  ```
  main() {
  ```

  Pase que algunos compiladores lo traten como un simple `warning`, pero C++ **no es C** y así lo refleja el estándar:

  > 3.6.1 Main function
  >
  > ....
  >
  > 2 An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
  >
  > ```
  > int main() { /* ... */ }
  > ```
  >
  > and
  >
  > ```
  > int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
  > ```